# TabelView Delegate methods using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift3, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am using RxSwift for TableView.I need to calculate height of dynamic cells previously I did it in WillDisplayCell delegate method. I don't know how to bind TableView Delegate methods with RxSwift. Can any one help?

Comment: It may be helped you- https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa

Comment: Thanks, but I need more precise answer.

Comment: Hi Mehreen, Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: Yes. It has been resolved.

Comment: Great , Enjoy coding...

Comment: Thanks for responding..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conform your View Controller

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
```

Then add this in `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

then you write `UITableViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: Thanks, I did it the same way. It works quite fine. My concern is that whether there is another way to perform the same task?

Comment: No, there is not, just the same task for `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: May I know what is the difference between `tableView.delegate = self` and using rx to set the delegate?

Comment: @Ryan I think they are the same

Comment: tableView.rx.setDelegate requires UIScrollViewDelegate as a parameter.

Answer (score 24):

Actually you can. Try this:

```
       tableView.rx
        .willDisplayCell
        .subscribe(onNext: { cell, indexPath in
   //Do your will display logic
           })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer for others. Most of the times, you shall answer, what was the problem, why this fix works, etc.

Comment: @ankitjaininfo The question was about how to bind TableViewDelegate methods using Rx, this is one example I wrote for the willDisplayCell delegate method, similarly can be done for the other methods.

Comment: I didn't know we can use WillDisplay Cell method like this way thanks...